# Storing csv files values in 3 separate lists

Tags: c#

I created a `.csv` file to use for a trivia game that stores a question, answer and 1-3 point value for each question. I want to store the questions in a string list, the answers in string list and the points in a int list. Then I want to display each question, answer and point number to the user one at a time. I am unsure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the `.csv` file code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        // The path of the file to write to.
        string filename = "C:\\Intel\\Trivia.csv";

        // Parallel array of related trivia data
        string[] questions = { "Question1", "Question2", "Question3", "Question4", "Question5","Question6", "Question7","Question8","Question9","Question10", };
        string[] answers = { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7","A8","A9","A10" };
        int[] points = { 1, 3, 3, 1, 2,1,2,1,3,1};

        try
        {
            // Write each element of the parallel array to a file.
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < questions.Length; index++)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(questions[index] + ","
                        + answers[index] + ","

                        + points[index]
                        );
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Data successfully written to " + filename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be written.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is desired output. Any snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind, this is really not the way to go about things.  It works but it's very brittle since you have to juggle three arrays and keep them perfectly in sync.  Far better to just create a class and keep one array of objects:

```
void Main()
{
    // The path of the file to write to.
    string filename = "D:\\temp\\Trivia.txt";

    var questions = new List<QuestionInfo>() {
        new QuestionInfo("Q1", "A1", 1),
        new QuestionInfo("Q2", "A2", 3),
        new QuestionInfo("Q3", "A3", 3),
        new QuestionInfo("Q4", "A4", 1),
        new QuestionInfo("Q5", "A5", 2),
        new QuestionInfo("Q6", "A6", 1),
        new QuestionInfo("Q7", "A7", 2),
        new QuestionInfo("Q8", "A8", 1),
        new QuestionInfo("Q9", "A9", 3),
        new QuestionInfo("Q10", "A10", 1),
    };
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        try
        {
            QuestionInfo.WriteCsv(questions, tw);
            Console.WriteLine("Data successfully written to " + filename);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be written.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class QuestionInfo
{
    string Question { get; }
    string Answer { get; }
    int Points { get; }

    public QuestionInfo(string question, string answer, int points)
    {
        Question = question;
        Answer = answer;
        Points = points;
    }

    public void WriteCsv(TextWriter tw)
    {
        tw.WriteLine($"{Question},{Answer},{Points}");
    }

    public static void WriteCsv(List<QuestionInfo> questions, TextWriter tw)
    {
        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            question.WriteCsv(tw);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you've got one array of questioninfo objects which keeps all the info for a single question in one place rather than spaced across three arrays.  Actually, there are lots of nuget packages which handle CSV files very nicely and I'd definitely consider using one of those but it's not that big a deal to do it yourself in simple cases like this.